# Trigger Doctrine Event

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have an event listener for `preUpdate` Doctrine Event which does the job just fine, but if request data is empty except `image_data`, it is not triggered. And it's logically correct, because there is no `image_data` column in an `Entity`, thus it doesn't see a field to change. The idea is to process `image_data` array, then do an image upload and finally store filename to `image` ORM column which works if one of the fields present in request. Let me show my code:

**Controller**

```
public function patch($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $company = $this->repo->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(CompanyType::class, $company);
    $form->submit($data, false);
    if (false === $form->isValid()) {
        // error
    }
    $this->em->flush();
    // success
}
```

**Form**

```
// ...
->add('image_data', Types\TextType::class)
->add('image', Types\TextType::class)
// ...
```

**Config**

```
# ...
- { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

**Entity**

```
trait UploadableTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @Exclude()
     */
    private $image_data = [];
```

How I solved it so far - in `BeforeActionSubscriber` I set `image` property to `1` therefore `preUpdate` is fired, upload is handled and real `image` filename is stored in result. I believe there is smarter way of doing it. Formerly, I used single `image` parameter for input/output and it worked for `preUpdate` because there is such ORM column, however I didn't like this approach because incoming `image` data is an array (`image_name`, `image_body`, `content_type` and `image_size`), while output data type is string (filename) and I decided to separate it (`image_data` for POST|PATCH|PUT and `image` is just result filename). How may I trigger `preUpdate`? :)

Comment: You can use an updatedAt field like this: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/known_issues.md#the-file-is-not-updated-if-there-are-not-other-changes-in-the-entity

Comment: I was thinking of using `updated_at` also))

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks! Please make it as an answer so I upvote it.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an updatedAt field like this: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/known_issues.md#the-file-is-not-updated-if-there-are-not-other-changes-in-the-entity

```
class MyEntitty
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime|null
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    // ...

    public function setSomething($something): void
    {
        $this->something= $something;
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can post code hunk as well as link might not work in future